# Logistic Regression model was not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, logistic-regression

```
class Logistic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Logistic, self).__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Linear(1, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer(x)

model_0 = Logistic() 

lossFunction = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() 
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params = model_0.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

for epoch in range(1000):
    yLogits = model_0(xTrain).squeeze()
    yPredicted = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(yLogits))
    loss = lossFunction(yLogits, yTrain) 
    accuracy = Accuracy(yPredicted, yTrain)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step() 

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print(f'epoch : {epoch}, loss: {loss}, accuracy: {accuracy}')
```

What is wrong with my code it wasn't learning at all it was just guessing the outputs and the accuracy is always 50% what should need to do to increase my accuracy and prediction probabilities.

Output:

```
epoch : 0, loss: 13418.1171875, accuracy: 52.0
epoch : 100, loss: 15.833349227905273, accuracy: 48.0
epoch : 200, loss: 13.117620468139648, accuracy: 48.0
epoch : 300, loss: 54.322288513183594, accuracy: 48.0
epoch : 400, loss: 81.71748352050781, accuracy: 48.0
epoch : 500, loss: 35.89091491699219, accuracy: 48.0
epoch : 600, loss: 35.788761138916016, accuracy: 48.0
epoch : 700, loss: 53.480674743652344, accuracy: 48.0
epoch : 800, loss: 111.3875503540039, accuracy: 52.0
epoch : 900, loss: 21.1838436126709, accuracy: 52.0
```

I tried to build a Logistic Regression model and the model isn't predicting the outputs it just returns all 0's when the loss function is BCEWithLogitsLoss()(accuracy = 52%) and all 1's when the loss function is BCELoss()(accuracy = 48%) what should i need to do to increase my accuracy and prediction probabilities.

Comment: Since you seem to work with a 1D dataset, maybe you should try to plot all your (x,y) points to see if you can linearly separate them or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you haven't applied a sigmoid activation function to the output layer. You typically apply the sigmoid activation function in Logistic Regression to the output of your linear layer to obtain probabilities between 0 and 1. Therefore, you will need to modify your forward function as follows:

```
def forward(self, x):
    return torch.sigmoid(self.layer(x))
```

Another thing you could try doing is replacing your BCELoss with BCEWithLogitsLoss which you can learn more about [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html). According to the documentation:

> This loss combines a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss in one single class. This version is more numerically stable than using a plain Sigmoid followed by a BCELoss as, by combining the operations into one layer, we take advantage of the log-sum-exp trick for numerical stability.

One more thing you could try out is increasing the size of your Neural Network. A larger neural network with more hidden layers or more neurons in each layer can capture more complex patterns in the data, but it also increases the chances of overfitting. You could also try changing the learning rate, which you can learn more about [here](https://deepchecks.com/glossary/learning-rate-in-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=A%20desirable%20learning%20rate%20is,rates%20result%20in%20faster%20changes.). Unfortunately, there isn't a one solution fits all kind of thing for NNs and so finding the right balance for the both often requires experimentation.

Comment: I tried all the ways changing the learning rate, adding more layers, changing the input data  but my model still gives the same output the output is all either 1's or 0's

Comment: If you add layers it is no longer a logistic regression.